# How to edit all CSS with same class name?

Tags: html, css, select

The [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) structure:

```
    <div class="big">
       <div id="big_1">
           <span class="to_select">d</span>
       </div>
       <div id="big_2">
           <div class="big_2_2">
               <span class="to_select">d</span>
           </div>
       </div>
           <span class="to_select">dada</span>
    </div>

<div class="small">
   <span class="to_select">I don't wanna select this div</span>
</div>
```

I want to style the `span.to_select` inside the 'big div' (not the span from small div). How can I select all `to_select spans` in [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) with one line?

Comment: you've already wrote an answer `span.to_select {}`

Comment: by standards, `id`s are to be unique; `.class` names don't have to be unique

Comment: I don't see what IDs even have to do with your question.

Comment: @j08691: Probably a holdover from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993267/select-all-item-where-id-isnt-an-id in which they did actually use IDs, and were corrected.

Comment: @blurfus only if you are not using js; if you are using them to apply style with css, they must not be unique.

Comment: Sorry..I didn't express well...I edit the post...Hope that now is clear

Comment: @nicael errr, not true! By web standards, they must be unique.  Browsers will allow you to include duplicate ids (and will render them in CSS as you specify) but semantically, they must be unique. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 and/or http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Would you accept my answer?

Answer (score 5):

To style all spans:

```
span.to_select{
// css properties
}
```

To style all spans in "big div":

```
span.big.to_select{
// css properties
}
```

In both cases `span` can be omitted (with your current code, where nothing else has  `to_select` class except spans).

Comment: This would be the best way to do it. ID's are unique per page, so you want to target the class ".to_select" instead. In order to accomplish that, you can use the selector above, which selects all span tags with the class of ".to_select"

Answer (score 0):

```
#big_1 .to_select {
   // the span.to_select inside #big_1 only
 }
#big_2 .to_select {
  // the span.to_select inside #big_2 only
}
```

as you say  'with the same id' ?

OR I think you mean the same class , in that case, just do this:

```
.to_select{
     // everything that has class .to_select 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The OP wants all the spans, not just one of them.

Comment: he said he with the same ID in the title of his question, which i misunderstood. I changed it a little.

Comment: I recommend explaining to the OP the difference between ID and Class

Comment: Your bottom code comment is misleading as well. That selector will select everything with a ".to_select" class applied to it, not just spans. the best selector would be: span.to_select{ //css properties }

Comment: span.to_select can do the job well. However it's also overqualifing, inefficient especially if you have large amount of css, the .to_select approach is better if span.to_select is unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry..I didn't express well...I edit the post...Hope that now is clear